# GPUImage crashing in iOS 8

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I have implemented a filter tool mechanism which has many filters. Each filter contains 2-3 different filters i.e. i am using GPUImageFilterGroup for this. Now when i updated GPU Image Library for iOS 8 compatible it shows "Instance Method prepareForImageCapture not found" and app crashes.

[image]

I also tried to implement the following code

```
GPUImageFilterGroup *filter = [[GPUImageFilterGroup alloc] init];

    GPUImageRGBFilter *stillImageFilter1 = [[GPUImageRGBFilter alloc] init];
//    [stillImageFilter1 prepareForImageCapture];

    stillImageFilter1.red = 0.2;
    stillImageFilter1.green = 0.8;
        [stillImageFilter1 useNextFrameForImageCapture];
    [(GPUImageFilterGroup *)filter addFilter:stillImageFilter1];

    GPUImageVignetteFilter *stillImageFilter2 = [[GPUImageVignetteFilter alloc] init];
//    [stillImageFilter1 prepareForImageCapture];
    stillImageFilter2.vignetteStart = 0.32;
    [stillImageFilter1 useNextFrameForImageCapture];
    [(GPUImageFilterGroup *)filter addFilter:stillImageFilter2];

    [stillImageFilter1 addTarget:stillImageFilter2];

    [(GPUImageFilterGroup *)filter setInitialFilters:[NSArray arrayWithObject:stillImageFilter1]];
    [(GPUImageFilterGroup *)filter setTerminalFilter:stillImageFilter2];

    GPUImagePicture *stillImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [stillImageSource addTarget:(GPUImageFilterGroup *)filter];
    [stillImageSource processImage];

    UIImage *img = [(GPUImageFilterGroup *)filter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer];
```

Its returning nil image. Can anyone tell me whats the correct way!!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, that wasn't a crash for iOS 8. You haven't updated your copy of GPUImage in a while, and that method was removed months ago in an update unrelated to any iOS compatibility. The reasons for this are explained [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2014/03/17/switching-gpuimage-use-cached-framebuffers) and I'll once again quote the relevant paragraph:

> This does add one slight wrinkle to the interface, though, and I've
>   changed some method names to make this clear to anyone updating their
>   code. Because framebuffers are now transient, if you want to capture
>   an image from one of them, you have to tag it before processing. You
>   do this by using the -useNextFrameForImageCapture method on the filter
>   to indicate that the next time an image is passed down the filter
>   chain, you're going to want to hold on to that framebuffer for a
>   little longer to grab an image out of it. -imageByFilteringImage:
>   automatically does this for you now, and I've added another
>   convenience method in -processImageUpToFilter:withCompletionHandler:
>   to do this in an asynchronous manner.

As you can see, -prepareForImageCapture was removed because it was useless in the new caching system.

The reason why your updated code is returning nil is that you've called -useNextFrameForImageCapture on the wrong filter. It needs to be called on your terminal filter in the group (stillImageFilter2) and only needs to be called once, right before you call -processImage. That signifies that this particular framebuffer needs to hang around long enough to have an image captured from it.

You honestly don't need a GPUImageFilterGroup in the above, as it only complicates your filter chaining.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My apologies that I didn't updated the code earlier. Can you tell me how I can use filter chaining beside using GPUImageFilterGroup. Thanx in advance